# Basic OSRM and OpenStreetMaps / OpenLayers questions

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, osrm

I'm trying to setup up a basic OSRM / openlayers map.

I have been able to create an openlayers app with a map and some data.
I have also compiled my own version of the OSRM server and tested it to return data.

I would now like to use it. And having searched around I see people asking complicated questions, but nowhere is there a basic example of how to use it. I have seen some of the websites that use it, but they usually minimize/obfuscate the code and it's difficult to get a basic idea of whats happening there.

The two main things I would like to do are:

1. Return a bike/walk route form the OSRM server, from what I understand the server only does car routes but in almost every live site I see they have walk and bike paths. How is this accomplished.
2. This should have been one probably.
   I need the most basic example of how to call the server function and then display it on the map.

I know I can create the URL call that's not a problem but it returns a .json file which I'm having trouble loading into my app. Apparently it accepts the the callback parameter but I'm not 100% sure what to do with it. Also the data comes back as an encoded and I'm having trouble with understanding the encoded polyline isssues.

So what I would like here is a basic example or a link to an existing one that does:

1. call the server url
2. the success function adds the data to the openlayers map and displays it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide a web-interface for a OSRM based routing service I would strongly suggest using a (customized) [Project-OSRM-Web](https://github.com/DennisSchiefer/Project-OSRM-Web) (the "official" UI found at http://osrm.at), or at least using the code as a reference of how to use the API.

**routing profiles**

You can customize what kind of routing OSRM does by specifying a [speed-profile](https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/wiki/Speedprofile). Several example profiles can be found in the [source code](https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/tree/master/profiles). As far as I know car and bicycle profiles are very well maintained.

OSRM [doesn't support](https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/issues/10) multiple routing profiles directly. If you want to provide multiple profiles, you have to run multiple instances of OSRM in parallel. OSRM-Web does support multiple servers.

**Server API**

Information about how to call the OSRM server API can be found [on the OSRM-wiki](https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/wiki/Server-api). The route output format for example is encoded in the [Encoded Polyline Algorithm Format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm).